# How to listen to outcome of a vscode extension task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have recently developed the vscode plug-in. There is a problem that bothers me very much, that is, how to listen the success or failure of a Task

I normally run a series of Tasks, if one of them fails, it should not run later, but I can't listen, like this

```js
vscode.tasks.executeTask(
  new vscode.Task(
    { type: 'try' },
    vscode.TaskScope.Workspace,
    'try',
    'ext',
    new vscode.ShellExecution('ll'),
  ),
)

vscode.tasks.onDidEndTask(console.log) // There is no telling whether it was a success or a failure
```

Comment: `TaskProcessEndEvent` has an `exitCode`

Comment: what if you define a problem matcher and look if there are new Diagnostics

Answer (score 0):

To listen for results of tasks started by your extension, provide a `onDidEndTaskProcess` event handler, which receives an execution object, including the `exitCode` of the process:

```
vscode.tasks.onDidEndTaskProcess((e) => {
    let task = e.execution.task;
    if (task) {
        const definition: MyTaskDefinition = <any>task.definition;
        // ensure this is the relevant task
        if (definition.myRelevantProperty) {
            log.debug("The test task returned " + e.exitCode);
        }
    }
})
```

You can also listen for a task start event; See [Tasks API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#tasks)